# How do I prevent standard users from creating new user accounts in ubuntu desktop?

Tags: 12.04, users

I need to prevent standard users from  creating new user accounts in ubuntu-12.04-desktop

Comment: What did you change in your setup that made a non-administrative user be able to do that? It is not possible in a default installation.

Comment: @rishab, By standard user what do you mean? Or how do you understand if a user is `standard` user.

Comment: If we go to user accounts in system settings.We can create two type of accounts: standard and administrator

Comment: Standard users cannot create user accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Eric Carvalho says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315788/how-do-i-prevent-standard-users-from-creating-new-user-accounts-in-ubuntu-deskto#comment399727_315788), only administrators can create new users. Standard users cannot do that.

When an administrator creates a new user, it can be an administrator or a standard user. But no standard user can ever create a new user account.

The user created when you install Ubuntu is an administrator, not a standard user. You should always have at least one administrator account--if you were to make all the users standard users, then you would be unable to perform any administrative tasks (though this can be fixed).

Perhaps you have an administrator who you want to be a standard user? If so, you can change that in any of the same places where you'd create new user accounts. If that's not working, make sure the user who you want to be a standard user is *not* a member of the `admin` or `sudo` groups. (The `adm` group is different; you don't have to remove someone from that to keep them from being an administrator.)

If that doesn't work or you need help doing that, then please edit your question to provide as much additional information as possible, including the output of `groups username` run in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), where **`username`** is the name of the user you're interested in.

Comment: I have tested with Standard user account.Standard user cannot create/delete user account.He can only do if he knows the password of administrator account.Thank you for your clarification

Comment: @rishabv I'm glad everything's working properly. By the way, if this answer solved your problem, I recommend marking it as the accepted answer by clicking the gray check mark to the left of it. This will make clear to others that your question is resolved (and that this might answer other people's similar questions).